# Saving functions as object and invoke them

Tags: .net, powershell, reflection, invoke

I did some research but haven't found anything suitable for my case. Is there a PowerShell native way to save function calls - or in the best case - parameterized function calls as an object in PowerShell to invoke them later on?

I want to queue some of them up and then call them in a row. A way that came to my mind was writing up the calls as strings and Invoking them through Invoke-Expression, but this seems very error prone.

Unfortunately I can't build a class for this purpose because we're using mostly PowerShell v3.0 and it's possibilities with functions. So I'm asking for a built-in / already existent way.

Comment: Powershell v2 and higher support Powershell Modules.
You should take a look at it: http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-modules,2-846.html

Comment: Hi Paxz, I will do that. It's helpful indeed, but not exactly what I need. Python can store references to functions in objects and you can call them like that: $x = func; $x() that's what I'm looking for :)

Comment: `$sb = { "Current time is $(Get-Date)" }; & $sb`

Comment: thanks @PetSerAl this seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the example provided in the comments by PetSerAl and indeed that is the solution, or comes very near to it and fits me right.

Here is a little more elaborate code example for everybody who want to try the same thing:

```
function Test
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ref]$Inp
    )
    return ($Inp.Value -eq $null)
}

$List = @({ $(Test -Inp ([ref]'ref')) }, $false)
$Result = $(& $List[0])
$Result.GetType()
($Result -eq $List[1])
```

If you double quote, in the curly braces like PetSerAl did, the result will be taken as a string, leaving them out will return the result as the original DataType.

If somebody has a good explanation how and why this works (I think this could be a ScriptBlock which gets executed by emulating a pipeline), please post them into this thread and I will demark this as answer and mark yours instead.